# Eventos botones javafx CRUD

Tags: java, javafx, crud

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto (con javafx y scenebuilder) donde tengo que guardar la informacion de un stage en la base de datos el problema que se me presenta es que el scene builder cuando intento meter el metodo que realize en la clase no me deja meterlo al boton como si no me lo detectase. Me podrian ayudar a resolver este inconveniente?

```
@FXML
 private void enviar(ActionEvent event){
CRUDProveedor puente= new CRUDProveedor();
  int id_ped_prov= Integer.parseInt(id_ped_proveedor.getText());
  int id_proveedor=Integer.parseInt(id_prov.getText());
  String nombre_proveedor=nom_prov.getText();
  int telefono_provedor=Integer.parseInt(telefono_prov.getText());
  int direccion_proveedor=Integer.parseInt(direccion_prov.getText());
  int web_proveedor=Integer.parseInt(web_prov.getText());
  int email_proveedor=Integer.parseInt(email_prov.getText());

  puente.insertar(id_proveedor, id_ped_prov, id_ped_prov, nombre_proveedor, telefono_provedor, direccion_proveedor, nombre_proveedor, nombre_proveedor, nombre_proveedor);

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En Scene Builder debes ponerle el nombre del método, en este caso `enviar`, justo en el círculo que marcas en negro, para el `On Action`
. Guardas el archivo y debería funcionar.

Answer (score 2):

A veces el scenebuilder hace lo que quiere y no funciona del todo bien, para esto puedes tener el recurso de modificar el fxml a mano por ejemplo en tu caso

```
 <Button fx:id="btnenviar" onAction="#enviar">
 </Button>
```

otra forma, ya que tienes el botón con una id y lo tienes declarado como atributo @FXML, puedes usar en el initialize:

```
btnenviar.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
        CRUDProveedor puente= new CRUDProveedor();
        int id_ped_prov = Integer.parseInt(id_ped_proveedor.getText());
        int id_proveedor=Integer.parseInt(id_prov.getText());
        String nombre_proveedor=nom_prov.getText();
        int telefono_provedor=Integer.parseInt(telefono_prov.getText());
        int direccion_proveedor=Integer.parseInt(direccion_prov.getText());
        int web_proveedor=Integer.parseInt(web_prov.getText());
        int email_proveedor=Integer.parseInt(email_prov.getText());
        puente.insertar(id_proveedor, id_ped_prov, id_ped_prov, 
        nombre_proveedor, telefono_provedor, direccion_proveedor, 
        nombre_proveedor, nombre_proveedor, nombre_proveedor);

   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Si decides usar la acción del botón mediante anotaciones @FXML necesitas:

1. **En SceneBuilder, escribir el nombre del método, en este caso `enviar`, en la parte destinada al `On Action` del elemento en cuestión** (parte marcada con el círculo negro en la imagen).
2. En el código, escribir la anotación y el método, como lo tienes ahora:

   ```
   @FXML
   private void enviar(ActionEvent event){
     CRUDProveedor puente= new CRUDProveedor();
     int id_ped_prov= Integer.parseInt(id_ped_proveedor.getText());
     int id_proveedor=Integer.parseInt(id_prov.getText());
     String nombre_proveedor=nom_prov.getText();
     int telefono_provedor=Integer.parseInt(telefono_prov.getText());
     int direccion_proveedor=Integer.parseInt(direccion_prov.getText());
     int web_proveedor=Integer.parseInt(web_prov.getText());
     int email_proveedor=Integer.parseInt(email_prov.getText());

     puente.insertar(id_proveedor, id_ped_prov, id_ped_prov, nombre_proveedor, telefono_provedor, direccion_proveedor, nombre_proveedor, nombre_proveedor, nombre_proveedor);

   }
   ```

Para más detalles puedes consultar: [JavaFX 8 Event Handling Examples](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-event-handling-examples/)